# Connect to external OLEDB data source from Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oledb, dblink, heterogeneous-services

I´m trying to connect to an OLEDB data source using an oracle dblink, I am able to create the dblink, but I get error ORA-28545

SQL> select * from dual@hsoledb;
select * from dual@hsoledb
                   ...............................*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agen
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from HSOLEDB

On the same oracle server I have a dblink to an ODBC DSN (this one is working without problems)

SQL> select * from dual@HOJACONTA;
D
-
X

I added entries to tnsnames, listener (PROGRAM = hsolesql) for the OLEDB link, created an initfile (inithsoledb) and installed ODAC, but it is not working.

Does OLEDB dblinks require additional configuration or software?